# Gmail Snooze error: moveSnoozes "service invoked too many times in a short time"

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I trying to find a way to snooze e-mail in my Gmail. Yes, I had Mailbox.app on my iDevice, but I want a way to Snooze or "Laterize" some emails.

I found a [Blog Spot post](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/gmail-snooze-with-apps-script.html) and a [Lifehacker one](http://lifehacker.com/5825634/how-to-add-a-snooze-button-to-gmail-no-extensions-required). The Lifehacker article just adds more pictures to the Blog Sport one. I followed the Lifehacker instructions. I made only one deviation from the code. In the two instances that  the code says "7", I replaced it with "200".

The code I have is:

```
var MARK_UNREAD = false;
var ADD_UNSNOOZED_LABEL = false;


function getLabelName(i) {
  return "Snooze/Snooze " + i + " days";
}

function setup() {
  // Create the labels we’ll need for snoozing
  GmailApp.createLabel("Snooze");
  for (var i = 1; i <= 200; ++i) {
    GmailApp.createLabel(getLabelName(i));
  }
  if (ADD_UNSNOOZED_LABEL) {
    GmailApp.createLabel("Unsnoozed");
  }
}

function moveSnoozes() {
  var oldLabel, newLabel, page;
  for (var i = 1; i <= 200; ++i) {
    newLabel = oldLabel;
    oldLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(getLabelName(i));
    page = null;
    // Get threads in "pages" of 100 at a time
    while(!page || page.length == 100) {
      page = oldLabel.getThreads(0, 100);
      if (page.length > 0) {
        if (newLabel) {
          // Move the threads into "today’s" label
          newLabel.addToThreads(page);
        } else {
          // Unless it’s time to unsnooze it
          GmailApp.moveThreadsToInbox(page);
          if (MARK_UNREAD) {
            GmailApp.markThreadsUnread(page);
          }
          if (ADD_UNSNOOZED_LABEL) {
            GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Unsnoozed")
              .addToThreads(page);
          }          
        }     
        // Move the threads out of "yesterday’s" label
        oldLabel.removeFromThreads(page);
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Your script, Gmail Snooze, has recently failed to finish
>   successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below.

Details:

```
Start: 9/10/13 12:16 AM
Function: moveSnoozes
Error Message: Service invoked too many times in a short time: gmail rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls. (line 24, file "Code")
Trigger: time-based 
End: 9/10/13 12:22 AM
```

Does anybody know how I can make use  of `Utilities.sleep(1000)`? Where do I type that in?

Comment: Its seems to be that by changing it to 200, you are creating 200 labels, for snoozing up to 200 days, which I can't really imagine why. Its best if you don't do anything to that script and see if it works. But only tomorrow after the trigger quota resets.

Comment: Patto, thanks for your reply. I initially made no changes at all to the script -- I had the default of "7". But that means I can snooze a maximum of 7 days in the future. I want a bigger delay (just like in Mailbox.app, which can snooze one month in the future), and 6 months in the future (6 months is about 200 days) seems like a good max. Actually, I don't need a 1+another day all the way up to 200 system. I'd be happy with 1 day, 2 days, 3, 4,5,6, 7, 2 weeks, 1 month, 2 months, 3 months, 4 months, 5, months, 6 months, 1 year, 2 years. But I didn't now how to skip snooze days.

Comment: Benny, pleasure.  The script you describe, would be somewhat more complicated that the one you are using, maybe you could post in the Google Apps G+ Community https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102471985047225101769 and someone may take it up.

Comment: Patt0, thanks again for your comment. Let's try to keep the script simple. If I just wanted to fix this "Service invoked too many times" problem by inserting the Utilities.sleep(1000) into my script, where *exactly* do I instert the code?

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is because creating 200 labels at the speed-of-code is too fast for Gmail and considered abuse of it's API. SO, as the error message suggests, you could use `Utilities.sleep(1000)` to wait a second between each label creation.

I'm not familiar with the script ([Boomerang](http://www.boomeranggmail.com/) works well for me), but you might try making your 30, 60, 90 180 day labels by hand and letting the script pick up on them. Then you don't need to worry about the label creation at all.

In an effort to help you better understand the code you are reading. Below is an explanation of what's going on and how to insert the `Utilities.sleep()`. You will need to decide for how long you want to wait 1000ms means that you're waiting for 200 seconds, and if you have 3 min to spare that will do just fine. You could experiment to see at what point the Gmail app says 'Woah that's enough there. Take it slower please.'

NOTE: I am not attempting to re-engineer this to allow for a better creation/management of labels. There are a probably a number of enhancements that can be made to the code, and although tempting, they will be left as an exercise for the reader.

RE your pastie:

```
function setup() {

  // This creates 1 label called "Snooze"
  // it probably isn't causing the problem
  GmailApp.createLabel("Snooze");


  // This piece is a loop that will execute 200 times.
  // It will do so as fast as GAS will let it.
  // This is probably where the problem is...

  for (var i = 1; i <= 200; ++i) {
    // Create the label
    GmailApp.createLabel(getLabelName(i));

    // We should wait a bit before making the next one
    // Utilities.sleep() will do well to go here
    Utilities.sleep(/*Milliseconds to wait*/);
  }

  // I doubt this is causing the problem either.
  // It's only one label creation
  if (ADD_UNSNOOZED_LABEL) {
    GmailApp.createLabel("Unsnoozed");
  }

}
```

Comment: Dear fooby, thanks so much for your reply. I wish I knew how to use  `Utilities.sleep(1000)`. Two reasons that I don't use Boomerang: 1. It costs money. 2. You need a browser (gmail-snooze can be done anywhere).

Comment: The line after the `createLabel` function, type `Utilities.sleep(1000);` Then, the script will wait for one second before continuing, and the error should be avoided.

Comment: Fooby, I keyword-searched for createLabel in my script, and there were  three instances. Do you mind going to http://pastie.org/pastes/8316159/reply and adding the line in the proper place, then pasting the new pastie link here, please?

Comment: fooby, thanks for your code in your edited "Answer" text. My new code in its entirety looks like http://pastie.org/8344932. In two days, I'll pop back in here tosay whether I'm stil getting the error message.